# Appending dataframe to an excel after evey loop in while condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have an while loop , whose output is written to a data frame , Then I am trying to write this into an excel file. But after loop is completed , I am getting the output of the last loop only. I want data to be appended , not overwritten.

```
            b=10
            a =0
            while a < b:
            
            ....
                ....
                # dataframe is created.
                ............
                #writing to excel
         
                writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter') 
     
                df.to_excel(writer,startrow = startrow)
     
                writer.save()
       
                startrow =  startrow + 1 

                a=a+1
```

The output should be like this :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REumb.png)

But the output comes as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u77vZ.png)

Comment: looks like your intend is off a bit. Do you want to intend all the items below the while statement by one tab. That should solve the problem.

Comment: I typed incorrectly here. Thanks @JoeFerndz

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few ways to get you to setup the dataframe. All of them will give you the same result.

## Using list comprehension as part of definition

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[i for i in range(1,10,2)],
                   'B':[i for i in range(2,11,2)]})
print ('df \n',df)
```

## Using append statement

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=None,columns=['A','B'])
for i in range (1,11,2):
    df1=df1.append({'A':i, 'B':i+1},ignore_index=True)
print ('df1 \n',df1)
```

## Using .loc statement

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=None,columns=['A','B'])
a = 0
b = 1
while b < 10:
    df2.loc[a] = [b, b+1]
    b+=2
    a+=1
print ('df2 \n',df2)
```

Output will be as follows:

**list comprehension**

```
df 
    A   B
0  1   2
1  3   4
2  5   6
3  7   8
4  9  10
```

**append statement**

```
df1 
    A   B
0  1   2
1  3   4
2  5   6
3  7   8
4  9  10
```

**.loc statement**

```
df2 
    A   B
0  1   2
1  3   4
2  5   6
3  7   8
4  9  10
```

Now that you have created your dataframe, you are ready to load them into an excel file.

This will get you to write the dataframe into an excel file.

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

writer = ExcelWriter('Pandas-Example2.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: If your problem was solved, here's something you may want to read about what to do when someone [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) your question.